# How can i add custom fields to moodle course like user

Tags: csv, moodle

How can i add custom fields to course detail? just like user. Is there any plugin to do? I tried [moodle-course_meta](https://github.com/frumbert/moodle-course_meta).And i can add additional fields to course,but when i try to use in upload course with and without adding `profile_field_` as prefix,It doesn't take the value from the csv file.
Eg. i created custom field for a course using the plugin and call it `note`
And upload csv file which has field name `note` and also tried like what we do on user `profile_field_note`. On both no luck. but the rest course fields such as shortname,fullname... are imported properly.
I am on moodle version 2.8.3

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it at the moment.

Some options are listed on tracker issue https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-34634

They include writing your own course format plugin or using the contributed local/admintool plugin, there are several links on this issue. The second option may be not properly compatible with backup/restore.